# Can a TCP listener receive multiple connections from the same IP/port combination?

Tags: tcp

I know that multiple TCP clients can connect to the same remote endpoint (e.g. my server runs on 127.0.0.1:8080).

I know that multiple TCP clients can connect from the same IP address. But when I test this (in my case using .Net's `TcpClient` class, they seem to be automatically given unique ports, but is that enforced?

Can my TCP listener/server have multiple concurrent connections from the same IP/port combination? If not, how can I uniquely distinguish my connections?

One edge case I considered is if two clients have the same IP4 address... or on any given network is IP4 uniqueness also enforced?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your question.  Please clarify.  The server uniquely distinguish connections by the Client IP/port combination.

Comment: The answers you received are quite good, but seem to avoid the direct answer: no, you can't manage server side multiple connections from the same ip/port couple. For it they would be **the same client**. And as explained in the answers, it is responsability of the client's stack ensuring that for connections to the same remote ip/port couple a different _local pprt_ is assigned.

Comment: Your question is puzzling. Are you sure when you say "If not, how can I uniquely distinguish my connection?" you don't mean "If so, ...". If they can't have multiple concurrent connections from the same IP/port combination, then you can distinguish them by the different source IP/port combinations, right?

Comment: While in practice what @RobertoCaboni said is true, in theory you could do something on the Application layer to deal with multiple clients using the same IP/Port.  For example a web site could create different content based on a cookie which could be different between each client.  I have not seen this done in practice, but it's possible. I'm not sure why you would want to do this.  Which is why I asked for more clarification in your question.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

When speaking about TCP, a connection between two entities is identified by the quadruple

```
<clientIP, clientPort, serverIP, serverPort>
```

This is why the same service (running on `serverIP, serverPort`) can accept

- multiple connections from different clients (entities with different IPs)
- multiple connections from the same client (same `clientIP` BUT different `clientPort`)

I'm not sure about .NET's implementation, altough I think it would work anyway, but when estabilishing a connection on the client side, you can also specify the port to which bind your client side socket; this way, on the server sidem you could identify incoming connections connections from the same host by their clientPort value.

Comment: Is it possible two clients can report the same IP, or on any given network are IPs forced to be unique?

Comment: IPs have to be unique, you cannot have two machines with the same IP (and this is one of the reason why we're moving to IPv6, there are not enough IPv4!). When on complex networks, it is possible that more machines get connected to the same component (like a NAT) that changes how the other machines outside the network see the first ones, but the IP is always unique

Comment: @Mr.Boy It depends on your definition of a "client". If, for example, I run two web browsers on my machine and visit the same website on both browsers, there will be two clients with the same IP accessing that web server. My machine will assign each outbound connection a unique source port which ensures the server can distinguish them.

Comment: I think it is a good answer, but your explanation would be great if preceeded by a direct answer to the main question of the OP (see my comment to question).

Comment: Mr. Boy, you can technically have the same IP address on multiple clients, but this will typically cause problems.  Network devices (switches, routers) typically determine where to send packets based on the IP address.  If two devices have the same IP address communications will be stepping over each other.  This can cause outages and network problems.
Things like DHCP were created in part to handle ensuring each client has a different IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Given the TCP/IP stack definition, no, you cannot enforce which port a client listens on from the server side.  When a client hits a server it sends a port number that it expects the server to respond to (the client will listen on this port) called a Source Port.  The server responds to that unique port for that particular client.

https://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/

Looking at this capture you can see the client sent a packet with the request to (Destination) port 80 on the server with a (source) port 54841.  This 54841 should be unique to that client from the servers perspective especially when combined with the Client IP address.

In more detail, the client sends a packet like this:
`IP: Src: 192.168.1.23 (client), Dst: 192.168.1.11 (server)`
`TCP: Src Port: 54841, Dst Port: 80`

The server responds with a packet that looks like this:
`IP: Src: 192.168.1.11 (server), Dst: 192.168.1.23 (client)`
`TCP: Src Port: 80, Dst Port: 54841`

Hopefully you can see that the server is able to uniquely track each request by the client IP/Port combination. A new request from the same client would have the same IP but a different Port.

IPv4 address conflicts are a problem for most networks.  Most networks will not tolerate an IP address conflict.  It is usually enforce by a competent network administrator or a DHCP server handling the IP addresses.  Someone can manually force an IP address on a client and this will cause problems with the other host that has the same IP address.  But this seems to be a different question from your original.

Comment: "This 54841 should be unique to that client from the servers perspective especially when combined with the Client IP address." Wrong. This 54841 should be unique to that client from the servers perspective ***only*** when combined with the Client IP address.